# Autoplaying an MP4 video in a UIView that is on loop like a GIF?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, video

Once users go to this specific page, I want the video to immediately start playing inside of a UIView with no controls. It will just loop like a gif. This is code I found off of github and it doesn't seem to work. It just shows the white UIView when I pull up the page. My file name is correct as well.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class RampWallPush: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!

var player: AVPlayer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Load video resource
    if let videoUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "small", withExtension: "mp4") {

        // Init video
        self.player = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl)
        self.player?.isMuted = true
        self.player?.actionAtItemEnd = .none

        // Add player layer
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        playerLayer.frame = view.frame

        // Add video layer
        self.videoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        // Play video
        self.player?.play()

        // Observe end
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem)
    }
}

// MARK: - Loop video when ended.
@objc func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.player?.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
    self.player?.play()
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is works you need to verify the file exists in your project and .......

```
    // Load video resource
  if let videoUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sample", withExtension: "mp4") {
        // exists
  }
  else {

     print("NoFile")
  }
```

So select the file and

[image]

---

You need to change the frame

```
 playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:200,height:300) 
 self.videoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
 playerLayer.center = videoView.center
```

Created a demo [Here](https://github.com/ShKhan9/Loopvideo)

Comment: Sorry forgot to include that it is in the project. So it looks like it works, but it shows a white box for a brief second and then shows the entire video as full screen off the display which I just want the video to be in the box. Also, how do I get it to load quicker without showing the white box when you go to the page?

Comment: Edit: I downloaded your file, and it still gives me a video that covers everything and goes off the screen. How would I go about keep the video constrained in a small box?

Comment: Changing the playerLayer fixed it! Thanks!